# Change "Final total" text on Woocommerce Extra Product Option Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gettext, translate

I want to change translate "Final total" on " Woocommerce Extra Product Option Plugin by ThemeComplete" for specific product.
My product ID is 9477.
I use this code but is doesn't work.

```
function change_plugin_text( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    // Replace 'Original Text' with the actual text you want to change
    if ( $text === 'Final total' && $domain === 'Final total text' ) {
        // Replace 'Translated Text' with the desired translated text
        $translated_text = 'Translated Text';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_plugin_text', 20, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late, maybe you can replace this line:

```
if ( $text === 'Final total' && $domain === 'Final total text' ) {
```

with:

```
if ( get_the_ID() == 9477 && $text === 'Final total' ) {
```

or better for single product page, with:

```
if ( is_product() && get_the_ID() == 9477 && $text === 'Final total' ) {
```

It should work.

Comment: First of all so many thanks for your response. I check it and does not work.